# Getting this error while making build in UNity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `D:\Dunk\.utmp\RelWithDebInfo\2p271f5i\arm64-v8a'
  [0/1] Re-running CMake...
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: D:/Dunk/.utmp/RelWithDebInfo/2p271f5i/arm64-v8a
  [1/1] Linking CXX shared library D:\Dunk\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\build\intermediates\cxx\RelWithDebInfo\2p271f5i\obj\arm64-v8a\libswappywrapper.so
  FAILED: D:/Dunk/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/build/intermediates/cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2p271f5i/obj/arm64-v8a/libswappywrapper.so 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && "D:\Unity Assets\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe" --target=aarch64-none-linux-android31 --sysroot="D:/Unity Assets/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot" -fPIC -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions -frtti -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -O2 -g -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--wrap=__android_log_print -shared -Wl,-soname,libswappywrapper.so -o D:\Dunk\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\build\intermediates\cxx\RelWithDebInfo\2p271f5i\obj\arm64-v8a\libswappywrapper.so FramePacing/CMakeFiles/swappywrapper.dir/UnitySwappyWrapper.cpp.o  -landroid  C:/Users/muham/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/121b6b243cedf8bef90d462440e4bf24/transformed/jetified-games-frame-pacing-1.10.0/prefab/modules/swappy_static/libs/android.arm64-v8a_API31_NDK23_cpp_shared_Release/libswappy.a  -llog   -latomic -lm && cmd.exe /C "cd /D D:\Dunk\.utmp\RelWithDebInfo\2p271f5i\arm64-v8a\FramePacing && "D:\Unity Assets\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy D:/Dunk/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/build/intermediates/cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2p271f5i/obj/arm64-v8a/libswappywrapper.so D:\Dunk\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary/symbols/arm64-v8a/libswappywrapper.so""
  'cmd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  
  C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
      @echo off
      "D:\\Unity Assets\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.22.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
        -C ^
        "D:\\Dunk\\.utmp\\RelWithDebInfo\\2p271f5i\\arm64-v8a" ^
        swappywrapper
    from D:\Dunk\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I tried to use multiple versions of Google ad SDK but same result.

I tried to change version of Unity but still the same. Please help me with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build settings and check if NDK is properely installed